# Ubicación en base de datos de las imagenes subidas a prestashop

Tags: prestashop1.7

ando experimentando con prestashop y he llegado aun punto donde no encuentro lo que busco.
Según la estructura de la base de datos de prestashop 1.7 tengo una tabla que se llama ps_category_lang en donde se guardan las categorías creadas por el usuario, pero en el backend el usuario puede subir la imagen de portada de esa categoría pero en la tabla no aparece el campo donde se ha guardado dicha imagen.

En que tabla puedo buscarla??
ya he buscado en todas las que hacen referencia a img:
ps_image
ps_image_lang
ps_image_shop
ps_image_type , etc

Y no encuentro donde se guarda el enlace a dicha imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La Base de datos de prestashop no guarda enlaces a las imágenes, lo que guarda es referencias de los ids, las imágenes las puedes encontrar en la carpeta img del sitio web. Por ejemplo:

public_html/img/c/  "c" category 
public_html/img/p/  "p" product

Por los ids de la tabla ps_image , navegas por las carpetas internas de la ubicación anterior y así obtienes donde se encuentra.

Por cierto en ps_category_lang se guardan las traducciones de las categorías pero la categoría se guarda en ps_category.